# To have non-serial unique labels?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

Nephritic syndrome
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{S.\arabic*}]

\item Lorem ipsun. \label{treatmentOne} 

\end Hello world!

\end{enumerate}

See the treatment option \ref{treatmentOne}. 

\end{document}
```

gives

```
Nephritic syndrome

    S.1 Lorem ipsun 

    S.2 Hello World!

See the treatment option S.1.
```

However, I would like to have unique non-serial labels which are made of letters and numbers. 
I do not like the serial identification of enumerate. 
It would be great to have it somehow randomized or mimicked somehow from the given words. 
How can you have non-serial labels automatically generated in `enumerate`?

Comment: Suppose the labels were random numbers. Would you want them in ascending order or in whatever order they are generated?  Also, what do you mean by "mimicked from the given words"?

Comment: I want them be readable randomized mixed with letters and numbers.

Comment: @Masi: Do you want to confuse your readers?

Comment: No. I need these IDs much because of huge amount of data. 77777777 looks horrible.

Comment: @Masi: Are we talking of `A1, A2` etc. ?

Comment: @masi If you have huge amounts of data wouldn't it make more sense to store it in a spreadsheet, generate unique codes there and then use something like `datatool` to do the final formatting?

Comment: `datatool` is not an option. I have many documents and I want to internal IDs within document such that I can ref by those IDs to other documents.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, but the prefix can be Nephr1, Nephr2, ... Something which distinguishes from other ones. I think there should be a function for this such that the user can also give the prefix directly. It would be great to know if you can write such functions to .tex document directly.

Comment: @Masi: See my suggestion, but there's nothing really random in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the version for the real randomization of the enumeration labels at the end of this post!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@randlabelprefix}{%
  Nephr%
}

\newcommand{\SetRandLabelPrefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\@randlabelprefix}{#1}%
}




\newcommand{\GetRandLabelPrefix}{%
  \@ifundefined{@randlabelprefix}{%
    Nephr%
  }{%
    \@randlabelprefix%
  }%    
}
\makeatother


\newlist{randenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[randenum,1]{label={\GetRandLabelPrefix\arabic*.},widest={\GetRandLabelPrefixAAAA}}





\begin{document}
\begin{randenum}
\item First  \label{Somelabel}
\item Second \label{otherlabel}
\item Third  \label{anotherone}
\foreach \x in {4,...,10} {%
  \item \therandenumi
  }
\end{randenum}

In \ref{Somelabel} and in \ref{otherlabel} and even in \ref{anotherone}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Update with a random suffix -- however, this will not work with `\label` and `\ref` (so far). Due to the different spacings of the letters the width of the labels changes -- a monospaced font would be better in this case.

To make it work with `\ref` I've to redefine the `p@` stuff, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage[seed=100,counter=myrandcounter,first=0,last=9]{lcg}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}




\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@randlabelprefix}{%
  Neph%
}

\newcommand{\SetRandLabelPrefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\@randlabelprefix}{#1}%
}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\dorandit}[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {%
    \rand\alph{myrandcounter}%
  }%
}



\newcommand{\GetRandLabelPrefix}{%
  \@ifundefined{@randlabelprefix}{%
    Neph%
  }{%
    \@randlabelprefix%
  }%
  \dorandit{5}%
}
\makeatother


\newlist{randenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[randenum,1]{label={\GetRandLabelPrefix.},widest={AAAAAAAA}}



\begin{document}
\begin{randenum}
\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \item \therandenumi
  }
\end{randenum}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Final update: With correct references, but this isn't very pretty still and it's only for one level of enumeration only so far**

It provides a FooXYZ label system, where Foo can be set with `\SetRandLabelPrefix`.

Some description: You can set the number of digits with `\SetRandDigits`.

Currently for this to work, use `\randenumlabel{somelabel}` instead of `\label{somelabel}`.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[seed=100,counter=randenumcounter,first=1,last=26]{lcg}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol} % Just for testing




\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@randlabelprefix}{%
  Neph%
}

\newwrite\randenum@storeenum
\newread\randenum@readenum



\providecommand{\@numofdigits}{%
  3%
}

\newcommand{\SetRandDigits}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\@numofdigits}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\GetRandDigits}{%
  \@numofdigits%
}

\newcommand{\RandCounterFormat}[1]{%
  \alph{#1}%
}

\newcommand\readrandlabel[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}{%
    \openin#1=#2%
    \read#1 to \randlabel@curcontent%
    \closein#1%
  }{%
  }%
}


\def\randlabel@curcontent{}
\xpretocmd{\refstepcounter}{\readrandlabel{\randenum@readenum}{\jobname.rand}}{}{}

\newcommand{\randenumlabel}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel
  {\csname p@randenumi\endcsname\randlabel@curcontent}%
  \label{#1}%
}


\newcommand{\SetRandLabelPrefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\@randlabelprefix}{#1}%
}



\DeclareRobustCommand{\dorandit}[1]{%  Must be robust due to \foreach and \rand
  \immediate\openout\randenum@storeenum=\jobname.rand
  \def\a{\@randlabelprefix}%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {%
    \rand%
    \xdef\a{\a\RandCounterFormat{randenumcounter}}% recursive built - up of the 
  }%
  \immediate\write\randenum@storeenum{%
    \a% write to the file
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\randenum@storeenum% close file
}


% Now some commands to provide `\RandLabel*` label format for `enumitem` lists

\newcommand{\GetRandLabelPrefixHelper}[1]{%  
  \randlabel@curcontent%
}

\newcommand{\RandLabel}[1]{%
  \dorandit{\GetRandDigits}%
  \GetRandLabelPrefixHelper{#1}%
}


\AddEnumerateCounter{\RandLabel}{\GetRandLabelPrefixHelper}{AAAAAAAAAAAAA}
\newlist{randenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[randenum,1]{label={\ttfamily\RandLabel*},widest={AAAAAAA}}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{randenum}
\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
\item \x  \randenumlabel{re::\x} $\longrightarrow$ \ref{re::\x} % Test the labels
}
\end{randenum}

\begin{enumerate}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \item \x \label{normal::\x}
  }
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

In \ref{re::15}  and in \ref{re::20} we see the correct labels 

In \ref{normal::15} and in \ref{normal::20} we see the correct labels (too)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to randomize some part of the prefix too? Etc Nepxyz, Nephel, Nepbay, ...

Comment: @Masi: Yes, this is possible, but not if you want to refer to it again with `\label`, since the labeling would call the counter formater (the label of \item) again and uses another label which is not what you want, unless you can omit the `reference` to it

Comment: I would like understand your last point better. Do you mean that such a procedure could be computationally heavy because it would call label-ref many times?

Comment: @Masi: No, but `\label` calls the `\therandenumi` again to write the labelling information to the `.aux` file. If `\therandenumi` produces a random output, it will use Nepxyz for item label, but \ref{foo}` will generate a totally different name, say NepABC -- this is contradicting then for a reference.

Comment: @Masi: See the update

Comment: Excellent! Do you have any ideas when such a feature could be incorporated into LaTeX by default?

Comment: @Masi: No, not really. I am not a core developper. I have a hackish for  solution for the references. I will update it later on.

Comment: @Masi: I've a new version with correct references

Comment: @Masi I very much doubt it would make it into the LaTeX core if that's what you meant, but it could of course be made into a package and put on CTAN. In that case it only depends on Christian (or someone else) being willing to do the work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. :D Of course it will not got to the core. Perhaps I will make a package of it, but not yet -- I am not fully satisfied with my `\randenumlabel` workaround

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You used the phrase "core developer", which was partly my reason for mentioning that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I understood 'incorporating into LaTeX' to make the code part of the core

Comment: @Masi: I took me quite some time to provide this solution! Is it acceptable -- yes or no? ;-)

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer! I like to think some days before accepting answers because there are so many things that often change.

Comment: @Masi: Alright -- In case of changes: Please ask a new question rather then ;-)