# Print random list (\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist) in sequential order

Tags: tikz-pgf

I declared random list using `TikZ` package and can get items randomly. But at same time I need to get all items in sequential order. How can I do it? Is it possible print `\mylist` items declared in noncomma variat?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \def\mylist{{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}}
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mynum}{\mylist} %Define the list 

\begin{document}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}
\pgfmathresult~\mynum\\

\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}
\pgfmathresult~\mynum\\

\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}
\pgfmathresult~\mynum\\

\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}
\pgfmathresult~\mynum\\

\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}
\pgfmathresult~\mynum\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did something similar a while ago, perhaps there's some inspiration coming from it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269937/to-have-non-serial-unique-labels/270706?s=29|0.0000#270706

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the commands

```
\newcommand\lengthof[1]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\nthof[2]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@#1\endcsname}
```

Let `<list>` be the name of a list that has been defined with  `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist`. Then `\lengthof{<list>}` returns the number of elements in `<list>`, and `\nthof{<n>}{<list>}` returns the `<n>`th element of `<list>`.

To iterate through the list, we use a `\foreach` loop (defined in the package `pgffor`). As an example, if the list is called `mynum`, then the code

```
\nthof{1}{mynum}%
\foreach \i in {2,...,\lengthof{mynum}} 
   {, \nthof{\i}{mynum}}
```

will list the elements of the list separated by commas.

The code below defines a list `mynum` as given in the original question and iterates through the list randomly as well as sequentially.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\lengthof[1]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\nthof[2]{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@#1\endcsname}
\def\mylist{{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mynum}{\mylist}
\begin{document}
\nthof{1}{mynum}%
\foreach \i in {2,...,\lengthof{mynum}} 
   {, \nthof{\i}{mynum}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
Random:
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 5}
  {\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{mynum}%
   \\\pgfmathresult~\mynum
  }
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
Sequential:
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \lengthof{mynum}}
   {\\\i~\nthof{\i}{mynum}
   }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-Ti*k*Z implementation.

- `\setmylist{<item 1>,<item 2>,...<item n>}` creates an ordered list with the `n` specified items;
- `\mylist[<integer>]` prints `<integer>` pseudo-randomly selected items from the list or a number equal to the total number of items in the list, if the optional argument is not specified;
- `\sortmylist` prints the list in sequential order.

[image: lists in order or not]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_Konstantin_mylist_clist
\int_new:N \l_Konstantin_mylist_int
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \Konstantin_setmylist:n
{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_Konstantin_mylist_clist { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \Konstantin_mylist:n
{
  \int_zero:N \l_Konstantin_mylist_int
  \int_while_do:nn
  {
    \l_Konstantin_mylist_int < #1
  }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_Konstantin_mylist_int
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp  { randint ( \clist_count:N \g_Konstantin_mylist_clist ) }
    \int_to_arabic:n { \fp_to_int:N \l_tmpa_fp }
    ~ -- ~
    \clist_item:Nn \g_Konstantin_mylist_clist { \fp_to_int:N \l_tmpa_fp }
    \par
  }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \Konstantin_mylist:
{
  \Konstantin_mylist:n { \clist_count:N \g_Konstantin_mylist_clist }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \sortmylist {}
{
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_Konstantin_mylist_clist
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \int_to_arabic:n { \l_tmpa_int }
    {} ~ -- ~ ##1 \par
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \setmylist { m }
{
  \Konstantin_setmylist:n { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mylist { o }
{
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
  {
    \Konstantin_mylist:
  }
  {
    \Konstantin_mylist:n { #1 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Create ordered list
\setmylist{one,two,three,four,five}

Random items equal to total number in list:

\mylist

Four random items from list:

\mylist[4]

Seven random items from list:

\mylist[7]

Items from list in original order:

\sortmylist

\end{document}
```